# Typechecking and generics in java generates warnings

Tags: java, generics, typechecking

I have the following inline Comparator.

```
private static class SampleSorter implements Comparator<SampleClass>{
    public int compare(SampleClass o1, SampleClass o2) {
        if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
            return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
        } else if (o2 instanceof Comparable) {
            return -((Comparable) o2).compareTo(o1);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which generates the following warnings:

> `Comparable` is a raw type. References to generic type `Comparable<T>` should be parameterized

---

And if I instead parameterize the types as suggested:

```
        if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
            return ((Comparable<SampleClass>) o1).compareTo(o2);
```

Then I get warnings...

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from `SampleClass` to `Comparable<SampleClass>`

---

And if I do typechecking:

```
    if (o1 instanceof Comparable<SampleClass>) {
        return ((Comparable<SampleClass>)o1).compareTo (o2);
```

I get the following **error**:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against type `Comparable<SampleClass>`. Use the form `Comparable<?>` instead since generic type information will be erased at runtime

---

And again, if I follow the advice of the error message:

```
    if (o1 instanceof Comparable<?>) {
        return ((Comparable<?>)o1).compareTo (o2);
```

I get this error:

> The method `compareTo(capture#4-of ?)` in the type `Comparable<capture#4-of ?>` is not applicable for the arguments `(SampleClass)`

---

Now I don't know how to procede, I really prefere code which is warning- and error-free.
**How do I produce warning-free code with the wanted behaviour?**

Comment: On a side note: what happens if o1 is comparable and o2 is not? It seems both could not be of Comparable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is there is no way for the compiler to know that what you are doing is safe. Instead you have to trust you know what you are doing and you can add this annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

tot he method or the class and the warning go away.

Comment: Yea, this works. But I've always considered `@SuppressWarnings` to be a bit ugly and it would be my last resort. Perhaps there is no better way, as you say.

Comment: The ugliness is self-inflicted, because you try to misuse the language/libs anyway: Either `SampleClass` should implement `Comparable`, then you don't need any `instanceof` nor the casts. Or you breach the contract of `Comparable` namely the commutative and transitive parts. To be clean you would have to step back and think about the overall picture andnot about some pixels.

Comment: True, in my case the actual code lies within a huge legacy application which makes the overall picture pretty hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if (o1 instanceof Comparable<?>) {
        return ((Comparable<SampleClass>)o1).compareTo (o2);
```

Comment: Type safety: Unchecked cast from `SampleClass` to `Comparable<SampleClass>`

Comment: Does SampleClass implement Comparable?

Comment: Traxdata: Some subclasses do.